# What is $\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}-e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{a-b}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

I'm trying to evaluate $$\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}-e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{a-b}$$

I know that the limit exists. The limit of the numerator and denominator are both zero when $b\to a$, so I tried to apply L'Hospital's Rule for $\frac00$ form, but the denominator is constant with respect to $x$ so it becomes zero and then the whole thing is undefined.

How does one go about tackling this limit?

Comment: What is $x$ in this limit? The limit appears to depend on the dummy variable $b$ in which case the derivative of the denominator is $-1$ not zero.

Comment: Limit is on b so the variable you are differentiating has to be b

Comment: Let $f(t):=e^{-x/t}$. Then, try to consider $f'(a)$ (by definition).

Comment: @CloudJR Thank you! I was trying to differentiate with respect to $x$, which is why it wasn't working. Differentiating with respect to $b$ makes much more sense!

Comment: You are differentiating wrt. $a$. Just write $b=a+h$ and send $h\to 0$ to see this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is nothing but

$$\frac{d}{da}e^{-\frac xa} = \frac x{a^2}e^{-\frac xa}$$

To see this, note that

$$\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}-e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{a-b} = \lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{b}}-e^{-\frac{x}{a}}}{b-a}$$

Answer (score 2):

Apply L'Hospital rule for $\frac00$ form & differentiate w.r.t. $b$ (where $b$ is taken as variable for the limit while $x$ & $a$ are constants) as follows
$$\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}-e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{a-b}=\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{\frac{d}{db}\left(e^{-\frac{x}{a}}-e^{-\frac{x}{b}}\right)}{\frac{d}{db}(a-b)}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{0-e^{-\frac{x}{b}}\frac{x}{b^2}}{-1}$$
$$=\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{x}{b^2}\cdot e^{-\frac{x}{b}} $$
$$=\frac{x}{a^2}e^{-\frac{x}{a}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Let
$b = a+h$. then,
for small $h$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}-e^{-\frac{x}{b}}}{a-b}
&=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}-e^{-\frac{x}{a+h}}}{-h}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}(1-e^{-\frac{x}{a+h}+\frac{x}{a}})}{-h}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}(1-e^{-\frac{x}{a+h}(1-\frac{a+h}{a})})}{-h}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}(1-e^{-\frac{x}{a+h}(\frac{a-(a+h)}{a})})}{-h}\\
&=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}(1-e^{\frac{xh}{a(a+h)}})}{-h}\\
&\approx\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}(1-e^{\frac{xh}{a^2}})}{-h}\\
&\approx\dfrac{e^{-\frac{x}{a}}(1-(1+\frac{xh}{a^2}))}{-h}\\
&\approx\dfrac{-e^{\frac{x}{a}}\frac{xh}{a^2}}{-h}\\
&=\dfrac{xe^{-\frac{x}{a}}}{a^2}\\
\end{array}
$